# Do the energy eigenstates still form a basis in Hilbert spaces where different states do not correspond to differing energies?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space

I'm new to quantum so apologies if this question doesn't make any sense:

Consider a Hilbert space of states corresponding to different positions along the x axis. If there is no associated potential function with position, the energy states will not span the Hilbert space as there is nothing to distinguish the energy of a particle for different positions. Given that the Schrodinger equation is derived under the assumption that the energy eigenstates form a basis, does that mean that it will not be applicable in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The energy eigenstates always form a basis, even when the potential is $V(x)=0$ everywhere. In this case, if the object of interest is a point particle, the Hamiltonian will be of the form
\begin{equation}
\hat{H} = \frac{1}{2m}\hat{P}^2 + V(\hat{x}) = \frac{1}{2m}\hat{P}^2.
\end{equation}
The kinetic term is still there. This describes a free particle. I believe that the problem with your reasoning is that the idea of "states corresponding to different positions along the $x$ axis" seems to imply that you are imagining "the states corresponding to the particle at rest in all of the possible positions over the $x$ axis", and taking this for the Hilbert space. After all, the states in which the particle is not at rest, but is travelling with some momentum value $p$, can be told apart from each other by the above Hamiltonian. This is not the way to think about it.

The idea of a particle being at rest is not well defined in quantum mechanics, due to the uncertainty principle. Take a look at the second answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/246320/can-particles-at-rest-have-wave-nature). The wave functions which follow from solving the Schrödinger equation for a free particle are plane waves $e^{\pm i p x}$, where the momentum eigenvalue $p$ is related to the energy by
\begin{equation}
E = \frac{\hbar^2 p^2}{2m}.
\end{equation}
The case of a particle at rest is given by $p=0$, so the wave function is not localized, it is the opposite, a constant in $x$. Note that this is a single state; there is not a different state for a particle at rest in each position, there is only one state in the Hilber space with $p=0$, called the ground state, which does not refer to any particular value of $x$.

You may then think about the eigenstates of the position operator $\hat{X}$. These do span the Hilbert space, but do not describe particles at rest in any meaningful way, since $\hat{P} \left| x \right\rangle \neq 0$. The state $\left| x \right\rangle$ does not correspond to a particle at rest in position $x$. It corresponds to a particle at position $x$, but it is not at rest, it's momentum is completely undetermined, just like the position is for the state with $p=0$ discussed before.

This is all related to the uncertainty principle. The energy eigenstates, which in this case are the same as the momentum eigenstates, do form a basis. This basis, however, is not related in any way to positions along the $x$ axis, it consists of states which describe the particle traveling with all possible values of momentum. The eigenstates of $\hat{X}$ also form a basis, they correspond to the particle in all possible positions, but with no well defined energy. You can't have both well defined positions and momenta, because $\hat{P}$ and $\hat{X}$ do not commute, which leads to the uncertainty principle.

Answer (score 0):

> the energy states will not span the Hilbert space as there is nothing to distinguish the energy of a particle for different positions.

The reasoning/conclusion in this statement is wrong. Not least, as you later stated the postulate, that energy eigenstates always forms a basis. Any observable, really.

In fact, if you consider a crystalline metal, the ions are arranged in a periodic lattice, and you can thus think of the sea of electron as seeing many different positions with the exact same potential.

If you object to that because the sea of electrons are localised to their specific potential well, then consider an insulator. Say, the ionic lattice of table salt, NaCl. The ionic character of this is so great, that we can essentially assert that the electrons are not moving. It should be applicable for your argument and show that it is wrong.

> If there is no associated potential function with position

It is not clear what you were intending to mean, there. It would require some serious weirdness before the potential function would be inapplicable.

Comment: My point with the potential function was to find some way of distinguishing between two positions with the same energy. If I had the state |x=1> and |x=2>, for example, and I wanted to express both as a linear combination of energy eigenstates, how would they differ if each position has the same energy?

Comment: Literally does not matter that they have the same energy. This is a standard thing to consider in tight binding expansion of a lattice wavefunction.